# Continuity of composition implies continuity of function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let be $f:→$ function and $T$ topology in $$. If $∘:(,)→(,)$ is continuous, then is $f:(,)→(,)$ continuous?

I can't think if this is true (I don't think so), any help is appreciated!

Comment: take $f=0$ and $g$ being any non continuous function. Then $f\circ g=0$ but $g$ non continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false in general.

Over $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology, let $f(x)$ be the characteristic function of rationals, that is, $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\Bbb Q\\ 0&x\notin\Bbb Q.\end{cases}$$

It is well known that this function is nowhere continuous, but $(f\circ f)(x)=1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, so continuous over $\Bbb R$.